# Big Entity Framework Query, How to pregenerate, or precompile this query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I Have a Big Linq-to-entity Query and it's seem to be very long to convert that linq query into SQL.

How can I Precompiled this query.
Is there a way to do that?.

here is my query.

```
 var ListLocation = from s in repLocation.GetLocationByPermision()
                                   .Where(p => (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.IsActive == -1 || p.IsActive == bIsActive) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.LocationTypeID < 0 || ViewModel.LocationTypeID == p.LocationTypeID) &&

                                                    (ViewModel.ListUsageID.Count() == 0 || p.Premises.Select(gs => gs.UsageID).Intersect(ViewModel.ListUsageID).Any()) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.City == null || p.Address.City.CityName.Contains(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.City)) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListCountryID.Count() == 0 || ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListCountryID.Any(pl => pl == p.Address.City.Province.Country.CtryID)) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListStateID.Count() == 0 || ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListStateID.Any(pl => pl == p.Address.City.Province.PrvID)) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.Street == null || p.Address.Street.Contains(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.Street)) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.CivicNumber == null || p.Address.CivicNumber.Contains(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.CivicNumber)) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID1.Count() == 0 || p.GroupLocations.Select(sg => sg.GrpDescID).Intersect(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID1).Any()) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID2.Count() == 0 || p.GroupLocations.Select(sg => sg.GrpDescID).Intersect(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID2).Any()) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID3.Count() == 0 || p.GroupLocations.Select(sg => sg.GrpDescID).Intersect(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID3).Any()) &&
                                                    (ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID4.Count() == 0 || p.GroupLocations.Select(sg => sg.GrpDescID).Intersect(ViewModel.BaseSearchViewModel.ListGrpDescID4).Any())


                                                        )
                               select new LocationViewModel()
                               {
                                   LocationID = s.LocationID,
                                   LocationTypeID = s.LocationTypeID,
                                   Long = s.Address.Longitude,
                                   Lat = s.Address.Latitude,
                                   FileNumber = s.LocationFile,
                                   State = s.Address.City.Province.PrvName,
                                   City = s.Address.City.CityName,
                                   Address = s.Address.CivicNumber + " " + s.Address.Street,
                                   Status = s.LocationType.LocationTypeTexts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LangID == lang).Txt,
                                   DefaultImgPath = s.LocationPictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsDefault == true && p.IsActive == true).FilePath,
                                   Location = s,
                                   HasPremises = s.Premises.Any(p => p.IsActive == true && p.IsDelete == false),
                                   ListGrpDescID = s.GroupLocations.Select(g => g.GrpDescID)
                               };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to pre-compile the linq. There is a decent MSDN article on the topic here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx

I've found the process a little cumbersome, and find myself reverting to Stored Procedures for the handfull of queries I need to write that rise to your level of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The guidance on pre-compiling views from Microsoft is probably your best bet:

[How to: Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx)

Comment: I already doing that for my .edmx file. The problem here is that nothing explain how to pre-generate a custom query stored in by example in a Repository File.